# Symfony3 Need to refresh after submit

Tags: forms, redirect, submit, symfony, page-refresh

I would like ***not to refresh*** my page after **the submit of a form**.

I use a *redirection* and *ask again for the list of entity* but there is ***no change***, I still need to refresh. *I had the same problem for other form but redirect solved it.*

```
public function handleClient($client)
{
    if (!$client->getNom() || !$this->clientForm->isSubmitted() || !$this->clientForm->isValid())
        return;

    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($client);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    // HANDLE REFRESH LIST OF CLIENT EXPECTED
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));
}


public function clientAction(Request $request)
{
    // ACCUEIL
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    // HANDLE CLIENT CREATION AND REQUEST
    $this->clientLogicHandler();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    return $this->render('CommonBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
        array('listClients' => $this->listClients)
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I found out that the problem is that I call the view directly without reloading from the Controller. Is there a way to call the controller so the new resource is rendered?

Comment: I still have the problem. I tried with $this->redirectToRoute('accueil', array(), 302/301); and no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, a redirection works only from the action, not from children function.
I only had to do a cascade to the action, and do the redirection if needed like:

```
public function handleClient($client)
{
    if (!$client->getNom() || !$this->clientForm->isSubmitted() || !$this->clientForm->isValid())
        return false;

    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($client);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    // HANDLE REFRESH LIST OF CLIENT EXPECTED
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));
    return true;
}


public function clientAction(Request $request)
{
    // ACCUEIL
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    // HANDLE CLIENT CREATION AND REQUEST
   if ($this->handleClient())
        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Client');
    $this->listClients = $repository->getAllClientInverse();

    return $this->render('CommonBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
        array('listClients' => $this->listClients)
        );
    }
}
```